# Not getting Google Doodles anymore

Tags: google-doodle

For at least a year now no Google doodles have been showing up on my homepage, new tab page, or just good ol google.com. This only happens when I am logged in to my Google account, they show up in incognito mode and when I am logged out. This also happens on any device I am logged into. I've tried clearing my cookies and cache and resetting my settings in Google Chrome, but nothing has worked. Help me!

Comment: Pending a better solution, make this [https://www.google.com/doodles](https://www.google.com/doodles) or this [https://www.google.com/doodles#archive](https://www.google.com/doodles#archive) one of your start-up pages or add it to your bookmarks bar for easy access.